# Why do i get 'no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String' when I pass a parameter to session.upload_from_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am developing a tool which uploads a file to Google Drive. I am using 'google-drive' gem.

In my view I have taken it as

```
<%= file_field :file, class: 'form-control' %> <br>
```

I call a method in controller for form which passes the     params[:file]

```
session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_config("config.json")
session.upload_from_file(params[:file], "right-on.txt", convert: false)
```

but on submit I get -
no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String.

How do I successfully pass the file to be uploaded to Google Drive. If I pass a local file path instead of params[:file], file gets uploaded sucessfully. I have to do it with file selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if multipart is set to 'true' in the form tag.

If not, set it true.

and instead of passing `params[:file]`, pass `params[:file].path.to_s`

the upload function is expecting a string as a path. `params[:file]` is actually a file itself which gets stored in temp folder while uploading. Check once without using `to_s`.

This should help.

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect your file upload input tag in the web console, you will see something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file[{:class=>&quot;form-control&quot;}]" id="file_{:class=>&quot;form-control&quot;}">
```

If you open the documentation for the [file_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-file_field) method, you will notice that it accepts first an object name, then a method and last options, such as `class: 'form-control'`.

I guess you would want to do something like this inside your view:

```
<%= file_field :drive, :file, class: 'form-control' %>
```

This will generate HTML tag like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="drive[file]" id="drive_file">
```

Then you can upload the file in your controller like you already do.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work. It think
    session.upload_from_file(params[:file], "right-on.txt", convert: false)
expects its first parameter to be a string that means I have to first upload a file. Then pass its path to this method to upload it on Google Drive. How do I first upload it then pass the uploaded file's path ?